Same Subspace Closure implies Same Closure in Ambient Space?
$\DeclareMathOperator{Cl}{cl}$
Let $\Cl_X$ be the map sending each set in a topological space $X$ to its closure $\overline{X}$. It is easy to derive the following identity:

Let $S$ be a subspace of $T$, $E \subseteq S$. Then $\Cl_S(E) = \Cl_T(E) \cap S$.

Hence given subsets $E, F \subseteq S$, if $\Cl_T(E) = \Cl_T(F)$, then $\Cl_S(E) = \Cl_S(F)$. But is the converse true? My intuition is no, yet I can't find a counterexample. I couldn't find any source online about this either.

The converse is true. Indeed, since $E \subset \text{cl}_S(E)$, we have $\text{cl}_T(E) \subset \text{cl}_T(\text{cl}_S(E))$. On the other hand, $\text{cl}_S(E) \subset \text{cl}_T(E)$, so as the latter set is closed in $T$, we have $\text{cl}_T(\text{cl}_S(E)) \subset \text{cl}_T(E)$. That is, $\text{cl}_T(E) = \text{cl}_T(\text{cl}_S(E))$. Since the same applies to $F$, we have,
$$\text{cl}_T(E) = \text{cl}_T(\text{cl}_S(E)) = \text{cl}_T(\text{cl}_S(F)) = \text{cl}_T(F)$$
